# What OODBMS are available for PHP?

Tags: php

I need an OODBMS for my website, to handle hierarchies and inheritance.
I use PHP and I have a feeling I am asking too much and will have to do with regular RDBMS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal opinion, is that there isn't much sense in using OODBMS over RDBMS.

Due primarily to a lack of a standard language, comparable to that of SQL, OODBMS are often niche, proprietary, commercial systems. You'll be hard-pressed to find a viable option for a language like PHP because of that. You'd probably have better luck finding something if you were using Java or C++. I did find this [comparison table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems), which might be of interest to you; though it looks like it was last updated in 2009; so be mindful.

Perhaps you could consider instead, a RDBMS + ORM solution using [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Comment: I came here after looking at this table because it didn't look maintained enough. Your answer is what I feared but thanks for the Doctrine suggestion, I will look into it!